# How to destroy the tab pages when navigating to the login page on logout in Xamarin Forms Shell?

Tags: forms, shell, xamarin

In Xamarin Forms Shell, the content of AppShell.xaml is:

```xml
<Shell ...>
    <ShellContent Route="login" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}" />

    <TabBar Route="home">
        <ShellContent Route="Tab1" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate home:Tab1Page}" Title="tab1" />
        <ShellContent Route="Tab2" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate home:Tab2Page}" Title="Tab2" />
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```

The login page is displayed first.
After user1 logs in, the tabs are displayed with user1 content. The login page is not destroyed (why?).
After logout the login page is displayed again. The page is not recreated as it was not destroyed at first. Also the tabs are not destroyed (why?).

Then user2 logs in: the tabs are displayed again, but not recreated. They still display user1's content.

After login i'm using this code to force remove the login page from the navigation stack:

```cs
foreach (var page in Shell.Current.Navigation.NavigationStack.Reverse().Where(p => p != null))
   Shell.Current.Navigation.RemovePage(page);
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//home/Tab1");
```

I'm using `Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//login");` after logout.

It seems the issue is caused by the static declaration in AppShell.xaml which caches all the created pages.
What's the correct way to implement that common scenario ? (i'm not using any flyout)

Answer (score 0):

For this,I think you  can refer to article [Creating a login flow with Xamarin Forms Shell](https://mallibone.com/post/xamarin-forms-shell-login).

The Shell is structured as follows:

```
 <Shell>

    <!-- Loading/Start Page -->
    <ShellItem Route="loading">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoadingPage}" />
    </ShellItem>

    <!-- Login and Registration Page -->
    <ShellContent Route="login"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}">
    </ShellContent>

    <!-- Main Page -->
    <FlyoutItem Route="main"
                FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems" IsTabStop="False">
        <ShellContent Route="home"
                      IsTabStop="False"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
                      Title="Home" />
    </FlyoutItem>
    <MenuItem Text="Logout"
              Command="{Binding ExecuteLogout}" />
</Shell>
```

For the login page, we would set it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             ...
             Shell.PresentationMode="ModalAnimated"
             ...>
    ...
</ContentPage>
```

And whenever you navigate modally, it is always a good idea to override the back button navigation in the code behind of the target page as follows:

```
    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

And there is a sample included in above article, you can check it [here](https://github.com/mallibone/ShellLoginSample).

Comment: I already checked it and verified that it is plagued by the issues I have described. Thus my question ;)

Comment: One thread on problem, we can discuss one problem in this thread.

Comment: For problem `Then user2 logs in: the tabs are displayed again, but not recreated. They still display user1's content.`   There is no need to recreate the page，the usual practice is to reload another user's data on this page.

Comment: Are you serious ? The best practice to prevent any bug and prevent confidentiality is to destroy things. I don’t have confidence enough in developers for that. Anyway that’s not the question. the same issue happens with the login area, where after login you can navigate back to it using a back button. Because the login views are not destroyed. For this one there is a workaround though.

Comment: And finally there is no way to know if the page is reopened from the cache without adding a global message that it listen. This is really ridiculous. The « « workaround » is to create a gas factory. Stop being like that and listen your customers. Stay simple. Stay efficient. Delete these unused pages.

Comment: I mean you can set different data for the same page if you haven't destroy the page after logining with another user.

Comment: In real development, we couldn't destroy the APP every time we switch users. When switching between different users, we need to request to load the corresponding data of the user, and then display it.

Comment: Switching user is only use case, it's to show a concrete example. So either you have a solution, or there is none and you have to update shell to have one.

Comment: `Switching user is only use case, it's to show a concrete example.`  I'm sorry, I don't quite follow you. Can you explain that in detail?